# Windows Phone - Showing items in grid in 'real time'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

I have a grid with 4 columns and 4 rows. After I press button i would like make it looks like game machine. I have Images array and I while I am looping through this array I would like to see this in action but all after I press the buttin I see my image in the last position. Is it possible to do it in something like ' real time '  ?

```
        int row = 0;
        foreach (Image image in images)
        {
            Grid.SetColumn(image, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(image, row);
            row++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for each loop before increment add a code

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1100);
```

Since its looping too fast u seeing only the last element with a Delay set you will be able to see all colors being set.

Comment: should I import smth special ? I am using MSVS 2010 for Windows Phone